# Active Directory allows creating InitialContext with disabled account

Tags: java, active-directory

I have problem implementing proper authentication based on Active Directory (Windows Server 2008 R2) and Java.

The assumed flow is that when the account is disabled in AD (properties → Account → Account options → "Account is disabled" checkbox), I should get the following exception from AD when connecting using `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`:

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 533, v1db1
```

This `533` tells me that the account is locked/disabled. And it works fine - at least in my dev environment. Enabling/disabling an account immediately changes the authentication result.

It doesn't however work in production environment at customer's machine... I can successfully create an `InitialContext` (no `533`) but the search operation a moment after this *successful* bind ends with error that I don't have necessary authorization to perform lookup.

What to look for in Active Directory configuration? I don't have any pooling and any AD replication...

[EDIT]: Wireshark dump

here's the request to bind to disabled account (only LDAP protocol decoded):

```
0000   30 50 02 01 01 60 4b 02 01 03 04 3c 43 4e 3d 67  0P...`K....<CN=g
0010   72 7a 65 67 6f 72 7a 20 67 72 7a 79 62 65 6b 2c  rzegorz grzybek,
0020   63 6e 3d 75 73 65 72 73 2c 64 63 3d xx xx xx xx  cn=users,dc=xxxx
0030   xx xx xx xx xx 2c 64 63 3d xx xx 2c 64 63 3d xx  xxxxx,dc=xx,dc=x
0040   xx xx 2c 64 63 3d 70 6c 80 08 xx xx xx xx xx xx  xx,dc=pl..xxxxxx
0050   xx xx                                            xx
```

and here's the response - ordinary `resultCode: success (0)`:

```
0000   30 84 00 00 00 10 02 01 01 61 84 00 00 00 07 0a  0........a......
0010   01 00 04 00 04 00                                ......
```

a response to invalid password is:

```
0000   30 84 00 00 00 68 02 01 01 61 84 00 00 00 5f 0a  0....h...a...._.
0010   01 31 04 00 04 58 38 30 30 39 30 33 30 38 3a 20  .1...X80090308: 
0020   4c 64 61 70 45 72 72 3a 20 44 53 49 44 2d 30 43  LdapErr: DSID-0C
0030   30 39 30 33 41 39 2c 20 63 6f 6d 6d 65 6e 74 3a  0903A9, comment:
0040   20 41 63 63 65 70 74 53 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 43   AcceptSecurityC
0050   6f 6e 74 65 78 74 20 65 72 72 6f 72 2c 20 64 61  ontext error, da
0060   74 61 20 35 32 65 2c 20 76 31 64 62 31 00        ta 52e, v1db1.
```

and sending correct password after the change, immediately results in successful binding.

By the way - using LDAPS (port 636) doesn't change anything - I can still bind to disabled account.

EDIT: Problem recreated on virtual server

I've enabled detailed logging of LDAP/AD events and that's what I got:

For **disabled** account, LDAP bind with **incorrect** to Active Directory results in single event:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       CENTRALA$
    Account Domain:     XXX
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       MY_ACTUAL_DOMAIN_NAME_OF_BLOCKED_USER
    Account Domain:     XXX
```

For **disabled** account, LDAP bind with **correct** to Active Directory results in these event:

1:

```
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Guest
Source Workstation: CENTRALA
Error Code: 0x0
```

2:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       CENTRALA$
    Account Domain:     MS
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        MS\Guest
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     MS
    Logon ID:       0x38cd57
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Is it possible, that correct login to disabled account over LDAP result in login into **Guest** account??

Comment: Are you really sure that the context is created immediate and not at the first lookup? Use Wireshark to verify that.

Comment: I can't use Wireshark right now - I have only phone access by friend employee. But he's checked the binding using Apache Directory Studio **started after disabling the account** and the connection (binding) is still successful.

Comment: Did you wait a reasoable time until information has been replicated through all DCs?

Comment: There is only one DC... And at the same time, `runas /user:disabled-user cmd` works as expected (failing for disabled user, success with enabled user)... Tomorrow I'll go there with Wireshark...

Comment: OK, please do so and report back.

Comment: I've edited the question - Wireshar dumps attached

Comment: OK, what type of bind do you perform? Simple or SASL with Digest or GSS-API? Please try a kinit with the disabled account and check what you receive. You should see a `KRB_AS_REQ` from your side and an error from the KDC. [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631) is a good overview of the eror codes.

Comment: Against what root DN do you bind? It maybe [this](http://serverfault.com/q/10208) cause that you can bind and then fail.

Comment: My root DN is 'CN=Users,DC=...entire domain' - so standard AD root. I use Simple auth. I'll check the link .. next time I'll go to this cut-from-the-Internet cellar :)

Comment: 1. This isn't a standard root, a standard would be either `RootDSE` or the root DN of your forest. Do not use simple, it transmits cleartext passwords. Use a least Digest-MD5 or GSS-API. Have you tried another client with the disabled account? Like Softerra LDAP Browser or openldap command line client?

Comment: I've tried pure Java code (in my web application) and Apache Directory Studio. I'll try other client. The problem is strange, because the same application and the same Apache Directory Studio works OK on other environment at client's site... But I'll try to resolve this mystery...

Comment: Hello Michael-O - could you look at the edited part of my question? I've added the events from event log...

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would have never figured that out. Stupid guest account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the solution!

The problem was ... enabled Guest account.

AD/LDAP bind to enabled or disabled account with **incorrect** password results in the following event:

```
Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc000006a
```

AD/LDAP bind to disabled account with **correct** password results in the following events:

1.

```
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Guest
Source Workstation: CENTRALA
Error Code: 0x0
```

2.

```
...
Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     MS
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
...
```

3.

```
...
Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        MS\Guest
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     MS
    Logon ID:       0x3ad7cf
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
...
```

4.

```
An account was logged off.

Subject:
    Security ID:        MS\Guest
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     MS
    Logon ID:       0x3ad7cf
```

After disabling Guest account, AD/LDAP bind to disabled account with **correct** password results in the following event:

```
Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Account currently disabled.
    Status:         0xc000006e
    Sub Status:     0xc0000072
```

Isn't it strange?
Isn't it a bug in AD/LDAP?

Comment: I think this is a Microsoft feature.

Comment: When Microsoft JIRA instance will be working again, I'll file an issue :)

Comment: Well, it is more likely that hell will freeze before MS will set up a JIRA instance.